# Collection of key-value pairs where only key type is known

Tags: c#, generics, icollection, keyvaluepair

I want a collection class of key-value pairs, where ill know the key type at instantiation level but ill only know the value type when adding a new element to the collection.

Consider a the code snippet below

```
public class Collection<TKey> where TKey : class
{
    public ICollection<KeyValuePair<TKey, IValue>> Col { get; set; }

    public void Add<TValue>(TKey key, TValue value) where TValue : IValue
    {
        Col.Add(new KeyValuePair<TKey, IValue>(key, value));
    }
}

public interface IValue
{
}
```

This works well, however, the problem with the above code is that the insertion type must be of type `IValue`, since primitives aren't implementers of `IValue` they cannot be added to the list.

I cannot use `object` inplace of `TValue` / `IValue`

**EDIT**

I would like to use any! type for the value parameter of the key-value pair. If possible id like to get rid of `IValue`. It was the only way i could get the code to compile

An example of ideal usage is as follows:

```
    collection.Add("hello", 10);
    collection.Add("peter", "temp");
    collection.Add("hello1", new Foo());
    collection.Add("hello2", new Bar());
```

**EDIT** 
I cannot use object since object is not all objects are seriablisable, however, i changed the implementation to

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var collection = new Collection<string>();
        collection.Add("hello", 10);
        collection.Add("peter", "temp");
        collection.Add("hello", new Bar());
    }
}

[Serializable]
public class KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>
{
    private TKey _key;
    private TValue _value;

    public KeyValuePair(TKey key, TValue value)
    {
        _key = key;
        _value = value;
    }

    public TKey Key
    {
        get { return _key; }
        set { _key = value; }
    }

    public TValue Value
    {
        get { return _value; }
        set { _value = value; }
    }
}

public class Collection<TKey> where TKey : class
{
    public ICollection<KeyValuePair<TKey, ISerializable>> Col { get; set; }

    public void Add<TValue>(TKey key, TValue value) where TValue : ISerializable
    {
        Col.Add(new KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>(key, value));
    }
}
```

The compiler says `argument type <TKey, TValue> is not assignable to parameter type <TKey, ISerializable>`

Comment: You have conflicting requirements. You're talking about "primitives" (value types?) you want to add to a collection that only allows types implementing `IValue`.

Comment: Can you explain why you can not use object?

Comment: Why can't you extend the primitives with IValue and use the extended class?

Comment: @CodeCaster you misunderstand. I only added Ivalue so that i could get the code to compile. The keyValue class required two types, however, the Collection class only defined one generic type. If i could get rid of `IValue` that would be great

Comment: @Jegan - i could write a wrapper class... but that's more of a hack i feel

Comment: Is your collection different from `Dictionary<TKey, object>`?

Comment: object is serializable, so is the build in ´System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<>´

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note beforehand : As a personal preference I tend to use dictionary for key/value pairs with unique keys or multimap/ilookup when i need duplicate key inputs.

---

If you use C# 3.5 or older you can use

```
var dic = new Dictionary<string, object>();
```

Assuming you're on C# 4 you can use

```
var dic = new Dictionary<string, dynamic>();
```

People like to use it to store JSON data for example.

---

There is a lot what you can do with Rx-Linq, but instead I would like to note that you can write:

```
var dic = new Dictionary<string, Lazy<string>>();
```

where you can store a script that generates the string.

Answer (score 1):

If you want your values to contain primitive types such as int, float ect and custom types, then you should use object instead of IValue.

```
public class Collection<TKey> where TKey : class
{
    public ICollection<KeyValuePair<TKey, object>> Col { get; set; }

    public void Add(TKey key, object value)
    {
        Col.Add(new KeyValuePair<TKey, object>(key, value));
    }
}
```

Also, you might want to change `ICollection<...>` to simply be a `Dictionary<TKey, object>` if you want fast hashbased key lookup during runtime.

Comment: Just as a side-note: this will heavily use boxing and might be a performance issue.

Comment: That is the obvious answer, but OP said _"I cannot use object inplace of TValue / IValue"_. Unless it's clear why not, I'd refrain from answering the obvious.